# Is there a way to change the extensions folder location for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: settings, visual-studio-code

I've put Visual Studio Code on [OneDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive), for the purpose of syncing it with its settings across my devices.

However, extensions are stored in `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` on Windows.

Is it possible to change this folder's location so I can put it in the main Visual Studio Code folder?

At first I thought that copying the extensions in the `resources\app\extensions` of Visual Studio Code folder will be a nice workaround, but that doesn't work.

I've also searched for a solution on the [documentation page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensions/install-extension) and in the user settings, with no results.

Comment: You can use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync) to sync settings between vscode instances. It works quite well.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I will try and use this extension, but I wondered if there was a simpler way, like juste modifing a config file.

Comment: Syncing settings between installations is not one of VS Code's built-in features. Hence the extension.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A little hack:

Create a symbolic link to the folder `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions` under the Visual Studio Code install path.

Comment: I wanted my extensions to live in `C:\dev\Microsoft VS Code\extensions`. Here's what I did: `mklink /D %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions "C:\dev\Microsoft VS Code\extensions"`

Comment: As of April 2018, Visual Studio Code, can be run in Portable mode, but adding a folder named 'data', inside the code folder.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable

Comment: Just a note: unless you're using Windows 10 build 14972 or newer with the *Developer Mode* enabled, the **`mklink` command must be executed elevated**! Anyway, I don't think this method of relocating a directory is a hack, not even little.  Pretty common thing mainly on *nix systems.

Comment: ok, but VSCode doesn't show this extension as installed..?

Answer (score 63):

What I did - after installing Visual Studio Code for the first time, I checked the documentation and added at the end of 'Target' field of editor's shortcut the following (there's a space before the two dashes):

```
 --extensions-dir="DRIVELETTER:\VSCODE\extensions"
 --user-data-dir="DRIVELETTER:\VSCODE\settings"
```

where DRIVERLETTER and VSCODE are the corresponding drive and directory where Visual Studio Code is installed. So mine looks like this:

```
"D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --extensions-dir="D:\Microsoft VS Code\extensions"
```

Here is for the user data directory:

```
"D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --user-data-dir="D:\Microsoft VS Code\settings"
```

Accessing the 'Target' field is done by right-clicking the shortcut and choosing 'Properties'

Anyway, there's a simpler solution to that problem - just use the portable version of Visual Studio Code. It works under Windows, Linux, and macOS:

## Enable Portable Mode

#### Windows and Linux

After unzipping the Visual Studio Code download, simply create a data folder within Visual Studio Code's folder:

|- VSCode-win32-x64-1.25.0-insider 
|   |- Code.exe (or code executable) 
|   |- data 
|   |- ...

From then on, that folder will be used to contain all Visual Studio Code data, including session state, preferences, extensions, etc.

The data folder can be moved to other Visual Studio Code installations. This is useful for updating your portable Visual Studio Code version: simply move the data folder to a newer extracted version of Visual Studio Code.

#### macOS

On macOS, you need to place the data folder as a sibling of the application itself. Since the folder will be alongside the application, you need to name it specifically so that Code can find it. The default folder name is code-portable-data:

|- Visual Studio Code.app 
|- code-portable-data

Portable mode won't work if your application is in quarantine, which happens by default if you just downloaded Visual Studio Code. Make sure you remove the quarantine attribute, if portable mode doesn't seem to work:

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
```

**Note**: On *Insiders*, the folder should be named code-insiders-portable-data.

**UPDATE 14.12.2021**

From [Visual Studio Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable)

Note: Do not attempt to configure portable mode on an installation from the Windows User or System installers. Portable mode is only supported on the Windows ZIP (.zip) archive. Note as well that the Windows ZIP archive does not support auto update.

Comment: I've found adding `--extensions-dir` and `--user-data-dir` cmdline switches to the shortcut(s) is not without caveats... If using the "installer" version (Windows) then there are many "context menu" options created such as opening a file (or directory or drive etc.) in vscode - these all need updating (in the registry) if you want to retain this functionality. HOWEVER, these all appear to be _reset_ when vscode auto-updates! When vscode auto-updates it "sometimes"(?!) restarts without the cmdline switches, so you're back using the default extensions-dir and user-data-dir!

Comment: It could be a hard-coded behavior of VSCode - to reset all startup options after update so the latest version can start in cleaner environment. But I don't know if this is the case

Comment: As I ran into that trap twice now, please note that portable mode only works mit the ZIP package download, not with any installer package.

Comment: Updated the post, seems it's not relevant anymore except for older VSCode versions

Answer (score 7):

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery

---

> `code --extensions-dir 'new_directory_to_set'`
>
> Set the root path for extensions.

Comment: only for this execution, not permanently

Comment: @HerrDerb so add it to a `.bat`/`.sh` launching VSCode then.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps for changing the extension path in VS.

> 1. Set "code" path in environment variable.
>
>    ```
>    path = VS_CODE_INSTALL_DIRECTORY/bin;
>    ```
> 2. Open VS , in VS terminal execute the below command.
>
>    ```
>    code --extensions-dir "new_directory_path"
>    ```
> 3. Install the required extension.

All Done.

*Note:Dont forget to vote the answer*

Comment: What does setting the environment variable do? This would seem to all be controlled by cmd line switches?

Comment: It can be used to resuse the extension withour redownload

Comment: This not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to change extension path for Windows.

1.Copy or Cut WHOLE extensions folder from this path:

```
C:\User\{yourUserName}\.vscode\extensions
```

2.Add a System Variable:

```
VSCODE_EXTENSIONS = X:\...\extensions
```

3.Paste extensions folder to:

```
X:\...
```

DONE.

Comment: it works for vscodium as well. thanks a lot. what more, this can also be used to make vscode & vscodium use the same directory for their extensions, thereby reducing duplicacy :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://dev.to/sulmanweb/vs-code-pro-tip-code-profiles-multi-environment-development-hg2), after installing VS Code we should make a language profilers folder like this:

```
mkdir code_profiles  
cd code_profiles  
mkdir code-ruby  
cd code-ruby  
mkdir exts  
mkdir data
```

For Windows, I prepared a batch file (`.bat`) for each language I work on, it contains this line:

```
Start "" "D:\programs\VSCode\code.exe" --extensions-dir D:\programs\VSCode\code_profiles\code-python\exts --user-data-dir D:\programs\VSCode\code_profiles\code-python\data .
```

This is for Python. If I work on PHP, I will make code-php folder, then make  `exts` and `data` folders in it and prepare another batch file for PHP, just like the one I made for python.

I put this batch file on the main project folder then double click on it to run VS Code with the preferred profile.

Answer (score 0):

To move extentions to new directory just do these few steps:

1. Move folder "c:/.vscode/extensions" to new directory ex: "F:/vscode/extensions".
2. Remove file "F:/vscode/extensions/extensions.json" from new directory.
3. Finally,in cmd execute this line after replacing your own dir (be sure to use this format:  `\\folder1\\folder2`):

> `code  --extensions-dir F:\\vscode\\extensions`