# How to change Extensions' location for VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My default download location for the VS code extensions is the C disk but I want to save the extension downloads on the D disk and use it from there. How can I do that?

I tried to change its path through VS Code setting but I couldn't figure out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_where-are-extensions-installed), extensions are installed in a per user extensions folder. For Windows, it is `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`.

You can change the location by launching VS Code with the `--extensions-dir <dir>` command-line option. Some other ways are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080793/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-extensions-folder-location-for-visual-studio-code).