Is it possible to install and setup Visual Studio Code for all users on a Windows machine?
We are migrating from IBM Data Studio to VS Code for deploying DB2 External Java Stored Procedures and in Data Studio (DB2 for Z/os Extension). We all remote in to the same Windows computer where we have setup Data Studio with a workspace. So that way all users who remote in to that computer have the same setup even new ones, there no setup needed. They obviously need to sign in with their own user etc. but connections and folder setup is all done beforehand.
I want that same feature in VS Code.
I've created a Workspace with the folders and paths i want, this works perfectly, but there isn't a way to pre-install extensions.
I want to ask if there is a way for me to setup all the connections and folder structure for every user, so the only thing they need to do is open VS Code.
Maybe I can change the extensions folder to be on C-drive so that everyone can reach them?
I've thought about creating a PowerShell script to copy my extensions folder to theirs extensions folder.
Maybe I could create a Profile everyone could use?
The easiest way would be for me to install vscode and its extensions on the C-drive.
I need to:

Add a proxy
Install extensions
Setup connections (I think this can be done by copying my connections.json-file to their own directory)
Setup folder structure/paths (Already done with workspace file)

Any ideas?
I've searched the VS Code documentation and couldn't find anything related to sharing extensions with all users on a windows machine.

what's missing after you follow https://stackoverflow.com/q/40080793/11107541 ?

When I try to se the User settings --user-data-dir="DRIVELETTER:\VSCODE\settings" i keep getting an error saying: Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: InvalidStateError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The document is in an invalid state..
